# ncat --ssl cloudflare.com 443 --- 0 bytes received

Tags: ssl, https

I just try to send raw HTTP request to arbitrary domains with https and found that the following command does not work for domains under Cloudflare.

```
$ printf 'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: cloudflare.com\r\n\r\n' | ncat -v --ssl cloudflare.com 443 > a
Ncat: Version 7.80 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: SSL connection to 104.16.132.229:443. Cloudflare, Inc.
Ncat: SHA-1 fingerprint: 3A51 2349 F9F9 7F93 DF88 48C4 2269 D35D 88EF B97B
Ncat: 40 bytes sent, 0 bytes received in 0.11 seconds.
```

But it works great for github.com and google.com:

```
$ printf 'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: github.com\r\n\r\n' | ncat -v --ssl github.com 443 > a
Ncat: Version 7.80 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: SSL connection to 140.82.121.3:443. GitHub, Inc.
Ncat: SHA-1 fingerprint: 1E16 CC3F 842F 65FC C0AB 932D 638A C64A 95C9 1B7A
Ncat: 36 bytes sent, 178023 bytes received in 0.28 seconds.

$ printf 'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.google.com\r\n\r\n' | ncat -v --ssl www.google.com 443 > a
Ncat: Version 7.80 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: SSL connection to 142.250.186.164:443.
Ncat: SHA-1 fingerprint: BE7B 2FFD 064B 94CD 2968 33EA DB41 8F0B 8275 5AD1
Ncat: 40 bytes sent, 50303 bytes received in 0.30 seconds.
```

Why there is no output for such domains? What makes them special? (curl or wget for them works fine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is nothing specific to cloudflare, but an effect caused by the pipe. After printf is done, stdin of ncat will be closed which makes ncat shutdown the sending side of the socket. The server receives the EOF caused by the shutdown before it was able to reply and closes the connection, never sending a reply.

Solution is to use one of the following

```
$ (printf 'GET ...'; sleep 1) | ncat ...
$ (printf 'GET ...'; cat) | ncat ...
$ printf 'GET ...' | ncat --no-shutdown ...
```

More information can be found in [this github issue](https://github.com/nmap/nmap/issues/1229#issuecomment-397642593)